# android market filters; screen size restriction to just one type

Tags: android, android-manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.helloworld"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"/>
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="false" android:largeScreens="false" android:xlargeScreens="false"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity android:name="HelloWorld"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I was playing around with the AndroidManifest market filter settings and I noticed something strange.

I uploaded a test app with minSdkVersion set to 4, and only smallScreens to true while all other sizes are false. I noticed that the portal was reading that the application supported-screens are small-xlarge even though I explicitly declared only smallScreens support.

I didn't see mentions on the Developer Guide that you can't restrict screen size support to just one type. Am I missing something in my manifest?

Answer (score 1):

You can only restrict the small devices from having the app available - all other screen sizes will have the app available even if it's is set to false in manifest. The difference will be how the device will scale your app, using screen-compatibility-mode or not.

See:
[screen-compatibility-mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html)